# Creating a local PDF file in Azure Function Linux consumption plan with Microsoft Playwright

Tags: c#, azure-functions, webautomation, playwright, playwright-sharp

I am using Microsoft [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) in order to create a PDF from a remote website inside an Azure Function (HTTP trigger). The method used is page.GetPdfAsync() that only handles a file path in order to create the generated PDF file. I would like to store the file in an Azure Blob storage container but as the GetPdfAsync() method doesn't handle stream or Azure blob storage, I am trying to temporary store the generated file. I tried to use different local folders such as **/tmp** or **/local** but each time I trigger the function I see an exception in the trace saying that the filesystem is **read-only**.

I read this [blog post](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-headless-chromium-puppeteer-playwright/) from [Anthony Chu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3199781/anthony-chu) so it seems that Playwright is now supported on a Linux consumption plan but in the article the generated screenshot is directly sent back in the HTTP response and never not stored on the local disk.

For the coding environment, I am using C#, VS 2019 and Azure Function Core Tools + Azure CLI for the deployment.

Any idea how I can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Page.GetPdfAsync()` returns a `byte[]`. You can pass null to the path and upload the resulting `byte[]` to Azure.

Comment: Good to know that we can pass null to the path and get byte[]. But in my case, it will be a production app with potential big files and concurrent requests. So handling as byte[] is not an option even if it is technically possible. I will ask on playwright github if there is any plan to handle output as a stream and/or an azure blob (using output blob bindings?).

Comment: There is no streaming. The browser returns a base64 string with the PDF. Which is converted to a byte[]. That byte[] is saved to a file if the path is passed. After that, the same byte[] is being returned whether you passed the path or not.

Comment: Understood. I will handle that as a byte[] then. I was not aware that PDF data was in all cases retrieved as a base64 then concerted to byte[] and finally saved locally on disk if path is provided. Is there any technical constraints to not save directly on disk or in a stream or may it be implemented in a future version?

Comment: @OmidB. I think that's fair feedback for the team.